# How to pass a path from a shell read command to wslpath

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to write a script that will pass the location of a directory dragged and dropped into the bash window through the `wslpath` tool when running in WSL on Windows.

```
# Drag and drop the directory into the Bash window
IFS="" read -r input
echo;

# If system is Windows Subsystem for Linux convert Windows paths to Unix paths
if [[ $(uname -r) =~ Microsoft$ ]]; then
    input="$( wslpath "$input" )"
fi

# Use eval to parse spaces in the path as an array
eval "input=( $input )"

# List files and directories
ls -l "${input}"; echo;
```

If there are spaces in the directory name it can not find the directory to list.

If I move the line `eval "input=( $input )"` above the Windows Subsystem for Linux conditional it finds the directory if there is a space in the directory name but doesn't if there is not a space.

If I replace the line `input="$( wslpath "$input" )"` with the following Bash replace expression it works with or without spaces but the drive letter has to be hard coded `input=${input/F:\\/\/mnt\/f\/}`

I've read multiple threads about the order of the evaluation of quotation marks in Bash, the passing of arguments to functions as arrays and then the expansion of those arrays but I'm really struggling with this and I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only one path you don't need arrays. Spaces inside paths are handled correctly as long as you quote your variables.

<sub>Actually, splitting the path into an array of words would cause information loss. You would not know if the array `(a b)` was originally `a b` (one space) or `a  b` (two spaces). Also, you don't need `eval` to split a variable into words. `array=($var)` is the way to go.</sub>

The problem here is that Windows pastes paths with spaces by surrounding it in double quotes. That is, if you drag'n'drop `C:\a` you get the string `C:\a`, but if you drag'n'drop `C:\a b` you get `"C:\a b"`. These quotes are not interpreted by bash as they are only input and not part of your script. `wslpath` does not interpret these quotes either. Instead `wslpath '"C:\a b"'` looks for a file named literally `a b"` residing on drive `"C:`. We have to manually remove the quotes that Windows' drag'n'drop inserted.

```
IFS= read -r input; echo
if [[ "$(uname -r)" =~ Microsoft$ ]]; then
    # is path quoted and contains a space?
    if [[ "$input" =~ ^\"(.*\ .*)\"$ ]]; then
      # remove quotes
      input="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
    input="$( wslpath "$input" )"
fi
ls -l "${input}"; echo
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much. I spent a whole day googling the problem and trying to figure it out and you're the only person that's explained the cause clearly.

Comment: Very glad I could help.